# How to continue execution even if a download is in progress?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm doing a process where some files are being downloaded. What happens is that my whole execution is paused when a download is in progress. Is there a way to continue with the process and keep the downloads in the background?

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
    behavior: 'allow',
    downloadPath: path.resolve(baseDir),
  })
await page.click(`#download`)

// need to continue
```

Comment: I tested it using https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download, and it works as expected. The download is in background.

Comment: Did the same test, and as you said, works as expected. I tried manually in the page I'm supposed to download files and it seems that the page is unresponsive until a download is finished. Is there any work aorund for that?